# $scope variable doesn't get updated in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I know this is a silly question, but I just can't get my scope variable to appear on my directive's template.I have a $scope.strans that gets data from an $http request. However, the $watch service cannot detect changes inside my directive's link and update it to the template.

App Directive

```
app.directive('ptransaction',function(){
return{
    restrict: 'EAC',
    template: '<h3>Did the client arrive? <% strans %><span id="queue_no"> //doesn't update</span></h3>',
    link: function($scope){
        $scope.$watch('strans ',function(nv,ol){
            console.log("changes made"+nv); //cannot see changes in strans
        )};
    }
  };
});
```

Controller

```
$scope.Call = function(trans_id){
    $http({
        url: $locationProvider + 'query_stransaction',
        method: "GET",
        params: { trans_id: trans_id }
    }).success(function (data){
        $scope.strans = data.transactions['q_number'];//Cannot update the strans in directive
    })
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use two-way binding in the directive's isolate scope?  Something like `scope: { strans: '='}`.

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't work

Comment: You could also watch the parent's property.  Something like `$scope.$parent.$watch('strans', ...)`

Comment: Your code in the watch string 'strans ' has a space after the variable name. Might try removing that.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the success function runs? Is the request working?

Comment: I got my answer. I checked my code and in my HTML I have two QueueControllers. I think angular doesn't understand the second instance of the Queue Controller.